# How to repeat list based on another list length Flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, widget

I have two list. one is banners and another one is offerData.

offerData:-

```
List<Map> offerData = [
  {
    'offer_name': "Aging in Place",
    'start_date': 1678682726649,
    'end_date': 1678682726649,
    'price': 100,
    'discount_price': 150,
  },
  {
    'offer_name': "Baking Mischief",
    'start_date': 1678682726649,
    'end_date': 1678682726649,
    'price': 500,
    'discount_price': 700,
  },
  {
    'offer_name': "Bon Appetit",
    'start_date': 1678682726649,
    'end_date': 1678682726649,
    'price': 250,
    'discount_price': 450,
  },
  {
    'offer_name': "Busy Budgeter",
    'start_date': 1678682726649,
    'end_date': 1678682726649,
    'price': 300,
    'discount_price': 350,
  },
  {
    'offer_name': "Catered Fit Daily Cater Diet to Go Dish Bliss",
    'start_date': 1678682726649,
    'end_date': 1678682726649,
    'price': 100,
    'discount_price': 200,
  },
  {
    'offer_name': "Chef o Matic",
    'start_date': 1678682726649,
    'end_date': 1678682726649,
    'price': 50,
    'discount_price': 200,
  },
];
```

banners list:-

```
List banners = [
  ImageAssets.bannerOne,
  ImageAssets.bannerTwo,
];
```

I have two banners and offer data is 6. I need to set banners as background image of offer data. so how can i set two banner at all offerdata. I need to repeat list from offerData list length. how can i repeat it.

I tried with for loop but the send me range error at list.

Comment: pls give a sample image or wireframe

Comment: You want `bannerList` and `offerData`  have same length?!

Answer (score 0):

here is an example that you can use:

```
List<Map> offerData = [  // your Offer data ...];

List banners = [  ImageAssets.bannerOne,  ImageAssets.bannerTwo,];

 var offerCardItems = <Widget>[];

for (var offer in offerData) {
  for (var i = 0; i < banners.length; i++) {
    offerCardItems.add(
      Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Image.asset(
              banners[i],
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          // Add other widgets for offer data, like name, price, discount_price and ... .
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

return Column(
  children: offerCardItems ,
);
```

I hope it works fine, but if it doesn't please share more detail like image or screenshot to able to help you.

happy coding ...

Comment: I dont think this serves the purpose of the question.

Comment: hey, thanks for your comment, as I read the question it says, that he/she wants to put every image as background of the offer datas.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem, I will share one hint, you may create new list  `List<Map> latestDataList=[];` and call a method `creatbannerList()` where `latestDataList` will add banner background images. You may call random function or you may call modulus of loop index.
Here is an example I am calling modulus of loop index.

```
List<Map> offerData = [
  {
    'offer_name': "Aging in Place",
    'start_date': 1678682726649,
    'end_date': 1678682726649,
    'price': 100,
    'discount_price': 150,
  },
  {
    'offer_name': "Baking Mischief",
    'start_date': 1678682726649,
    'end_date': 1678682726649,
    'price': 500,
    'discount_price': 700,
  },
  {
    'offer_name': "Bon Appetit",
    'start_date': 1678682726649,
    'end_date': 1678682726649,
    'price': 250,
    'discount_price': 450,
  },
  {
    'offer_name': "Busy Budgeter",
    'start_date': 1678682726649,
    'end_date': 1678682726649,
    'price': 300,
    'discount_price': 350,
  },
  {
    'offer_name': "Catered Fit Daily Cater Diet to Go Dish Bliss",
    'start_date': 1678682726649,
    'end_date': 1678682726649,
    'price': 100,
    'discount_price': 200,
  },
  {
    'offer_name': "Chef o Matic",
    'start_date': 1678682726649,
    'end_date': 1678682726649,
    'price': 50,
    'discount_price': 200,
  },
];

List banners = [
  ImageAssets.bannerOne,
  ImageAssets.bannerTwo,
];

List<Map> latestDataList=[];

void  creatbannerList(){
  for(int  i=0;i<offerData.length;i++){
    int bannerindex=i%2;
    latestDataList.add(
      {
        'offer_name': offerData[i]["offer_name"],
        'start_date': offerData[i]["start_date"],
        'end_date': offerData[i]["end_date"],
        'price': offerData[i]["price"],
        'discount_price': offerData[i]["discount_price"],
        'bgImage':banners[bannerindex],
      }

    );
  }
}
```